# How to remove time section from date time picker?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows desktop with an SQL back-end. I am trying to run an SQL query that will have the date time in format "yyyy-mm-dd." My problem is I need to see all entries from that date. Currently my date time picker keeps giving me a time with my selection. I need to remove the time portion. I tried a couple of solutions from the web but when I try and display the date time picker in a message box to see what the value is it says false. I am not sure how to change the output value in the custom field to remove this. Here is my code.

This is in on my load event:

```
'date time picker set up
    DTPPromiseDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DTPPromiseDate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Then in a button click event, is a message box to display what was selected in the date time picker. I want to get my message box working correctly before I try and run SQL queries with it.

```
MsgBox(DTPPromiseDate.Value)
```

-------------------------UPDATE-----------------

This code appeared as I wanted it to but I am still trying to work it into my query.

```
DTPPromiseDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Well this is a convenient time to learn: A) Parameterized Queries/Prepared Statements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx; and B) The `DateTime.ToString(String)` method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: "False" is weird. What do you get from  MsgBox(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))?

Comment: @EBrown I dont need it to be a string, It still needs to be a date time, clweeks, let me try that.

Comment: I don't think you understand how a `DateTime` works. It stores both values; you decide which to use where and how, using some sort of `ToString(String)` or other call.

Comment: @clweeks that worked, I pulled my solution from another form website and it had an equal sign in it and I think that is what the false was coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the formatting string that you used in the picker's custom format to the message box text as well.